# Windows Server 2003 IIS Renders ASP.NET 4.0 pages as blank

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

I have a web project which works fine on my local development machine.

I copied the project to our UAT server, setup a virtual directory pointing to the project and configured it to run on .NET Framework 4.0. I even added the Default.aspx page to the Documents tab. I configured Directory Security to use Windows Authentication.

When i try to access any web page within this application, IIS responds with a blank page. I looked through the event logs and don't see any errors anywhere.

Can someone please help me understand what's going on and how to remedy this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003, after the install of .NET Framework 4.0, the process of creating Web Sites or Virtual Directories that run under .NET Framework 4.0 is as follows:

1. Create a new application pool.
   Applications running under different
   frameworks can't be hosted in the
   same application pool, i.e. create
   an application pool perf framework.
2. Next, if you are creating a local
   intranet site or virtual directory,
   ensure that you don't have "dots" in
   the application name. Browsers
   confuse the dots to be external web
   sites, forcing them to run under
   internet zone as appose to the
   intranet zone.
3. Once you create your web site or
   virtual directory, make sure that it
   runs under an application pool
   dedicated for .NET 4.0 applications.
4. Ensure that when creating your
   website or virtual directory, you
   click on the ASP.NET tab and select
   version 4.0 from the drop down.
5. Then you may configure as per
   normal, with any other additional
   settings you may require.

Hope this helps someone experiencing similar issues. Took a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just seeing a white page with no errors in the event log, it sounds like it could be a problem with the application rather than the hosting environment.

However, there are a few things you could try to doing to troubleshoot this.

- Check folder permissions.  Try allowing "Everyone" access on your webroot folder and see if that makes any difference.
- Confirm that the IIS path is set up correctly but putting a text file in your webroot folder, and then browsing to it and verifying that it's contents are displayed.
- Create a basic test.aspx page without any script, just a "Hello World" bit of text, and try browsing to it.  Confirm that it displays the correct content.
- Edit web.config and turn off custom errors
- Try re-registering the ASP.NET extensions with IIS using aspnet_iis ([details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=VS.100).aspx))

Hopefully, one of these tests will be able to give you some kind of detailed error message or more insight into the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Mun. Unfortunately, none of the steps you recommended work.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c What happens when you try and browse to a text file and your webroot folder has allowed "Everyone" full access?

Comment: That works - i can see the contents of the text file. Tried a simple test aspx page - doesn't work. Almost like IIS unable to render aspx pages under .net 4 configuration. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Tried browsing to a non-existent aspx page and it also returns blank as appose to an error.

Comment: It sounds like something has gone awry with your ASP.NET configuration.  Have you tried running "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i" at the command prompt?  This can often fix a lot of these types of problems.

Comment: The next thing I'd probably do is try going into Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS, find ASP.NET and disable, save, and then re-enable to force IIS to reset it's settings.

Comment: Looking at this - http://forums.iis.net/t/1147821.aspx, you may also need to enable the "Static Content" setting in Windows Features -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features.